# Laravel: Variables showing as undefined when appending to table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm retrieving data from a database via AJAX GET call, ater succesfull response I print the data by appending an html template to my table, I am getting the results back all right (in JSON format) but when appending them to table they all appear as undefined:

Here is my controller method:

```js
public function index()
    {
        $reviews = Review::all();
  
  return response()->json([
  
            'success' => 'Todas las opiniones recogidas',
   'reviews' => $reviews,
        ]);
    }
```

This is my JQuery code where I append the results, I'm fairly certain the error is in here:

```js
$.ajax({

                    async: true,
                    url: '/reviews',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
    
                    success: function (data) { 
       
            $('.row[data-link=' + linked_entry + ']').remove();
     
         $.each(data, function (index, item) {
     
             var reviews_row = '<tr class="row" data-link="reviews">';
                            reviews_row += '<td>' + data.body + '</td>';
                            reviews_row += '<td>' + data.author + '</td>';
                            reviews_row += '<td>' + data.site + '</td>';
                            reviews_row += '<td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" name="isVisible" '+(data.isVisible ? 'checked' : '')+'></td>';
                            reviews_row += '</tr>';
 
             $('.entry_table_container[data-link=' + linked_entry + ']').append(reviews_row);
                        });
        
                 
                    },
   
           error: function (data){
                        var errors = data.responseJSON;
                        console.log(errors);
                    }
    
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use `item` instead of `data` inside of your `each` function.

Comment: You're looping on data but you've nested all the reviews under the reviews key in your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

`$.each(data, function (index, item) {`

To this:

`$.each(data.reviews, function (index, item) {`

and then:

item.body, item.author etc in your loop as one of the other contributors mentioned